# Unmarshalling a JSON message with protobuf subfields

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers

I'm receiving a JSON blob from a Kubernetes API that contains a type that includes a protobuf subfield. Since that protobuf includes `oneof` fields, I have to use `golang/protobuf/jsonpb` and not `encoding/json`.

I've reproduced this simply here:

**client.proto**

```
message Latency {
  oneof latency_type {
    StaticLatency static = 1;
    NormalLatency normal = 2;
  }
}
```

**client.go**:

```
type Metadata struct {
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

type LatencyWrapper struct {
    Meta    Metadata `json:"meta"`
    Latency Latency  `json:"latency"`
}
```

How can I unmarshal this message? I think I want something like this:

```
func (lw *LatencyWrapper) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var parts map[string]string = Something()

    json.Unmarshal(parts["meta"], &lw.meta)
    jsonpb.Unmarshal(parts["latency"], &lw.latency)

    return nil
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Michael